# autotools -- make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: makefile, autotools

I created a simple test application + library that I am building using autotools. The problem is that the Makefile that is generated doesn't understand the "all" target.

Makefile.am:

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
SUBDIRS = src
VERSION=0:0:0
EXTRA_DIST = autogen.sh

bin_PROGRAMS = testApp

libtest_la_SOURCES = src/testLibrary.c
libtest_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info ${VERSION}

testApp_SOURCES = src/testApp.c
testApp_LDADD = libtest.la
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libtest.la
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT(foobar, 1.0, me@mail.com)
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR(config)
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR(src)
AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
LT_INIT
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

Output of the command "make":

```
Making all in src
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Yet make understands the "testApp" target and builds it successfully. From my limited knowledge of autotools, the bin_PROGRAMS variable should supply the "all" target with its data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be combining recursive and non-recursive make rules.

If you remove this line:

```
SUBDIRS = src
```

this error might go away.  It's looking for an `all` rule in `src/Makefile`.